# Showing only one country using Gmaps

Tags: c#, winforms, google-maps, maps

I'm working on a project using GreatMaps https://greatmaps.codeplex.com/ Library in c#, is it possible to show only one country like Germany kindly help.

its not duplicate of any question on stackoverflow, i'm using gmaps library not google maps.